# Laravel test not working when running whole test suite, ReflectionException : Class config does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, lumen

I am currently developing a test suite for my lumen API. I am using lumen 5.6 with phpunit 7.

I have the following test:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExportControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testGetHeader()
    {
        $controller = app()->make("App\Http\Controllers\ExportController");
        $header = $controller->getHeader();
        self::assertNotNull($header);

        self::assertEquals($header[0], "title");
    }

 }
```

With `TestCase.php`:

```
namespace Tests;

abstract class TestCase extends \Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    }

}
```

When I run the test individually with the following it works fine:

> phpunit --bootstrap path_to_project\bootstrap\app.php --configuration
>   path_to_project\phpunit.xml
>   path_to_project\tests\app\Http\Controllers\ExportControllerTest.php

B but when I try to run the whole test suite with:

> phpunit --bootstrap path_to_project\bootstrap\app.php --configuration
>   path_to_project\phpunit.xml path_to_project\tests

I get the following error:

```
ReflectionException : Class config does not exist
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:767
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:646
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:601
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Application.php:223
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1210
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:259
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:89
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:65
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:327
 path_to_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:223
 path_to_project\app\Services\RawQueryService.php:114
 path_to_project\app\Services\RawQueryService.php:81
 path_to_project\app\Services\RawQueryService.php:37
 path_to_project\app\Services\SearchService.php:56
 path_to_project\app\Http\Controllers\ExportController.php:83
 path_to_project\tests\app\Http\Controllers\ExportControllerTest.php:19
```

Where the config `phpunit.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_PORT" value="11009"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test"/>
        <env name="DB_HOST" value="localhost"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="null"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="null"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

None of the properties in my `.env` file contain spaces, as I noticed this is often listed as the cause for this error.

Anyone have any idea as to what may cause this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect it's arising because you haven't added an import of config in your exportcontroller class. Can you add "use Config;" to the top of your path_to_project\app\Http\Controllers\ExportController.php file and run the test again please?

Comment: @pseudoanime, I tried your suggestion but sadly it makes no difference :(

Comment: Try adding "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;" and see please.

Comment: @pseudoanime, I added that to the imports in `ExportControllerTest.php` but I still get the same error

Comment: @pseudoanime, I used the wrong import for `Testcase`, it was the lumen default instead of my own class definition. Thank you anyway :)